# What could cause a dead creature to immediatley (or almost) turn into crystal/gemstones

Tags: science-based, vampires

So in my world Vampires are their own species similar to humans, almost no magic is involved. When they die I have it so they would, in a relatively short amount of time, turn into diamond or other gemstones. I have heard of people turning ashes into diamonds but are there other funky chemical changes that can turn flesh, bone, or blood into other type of gemstones?

*yes I stole this idea somewhat from Resident Evil Village I have no shame*

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please take our [tour] and read-up in the [help] about how we work. At the moment the question is a bit vague, seems to lack any research into basic chemistry or the sheer pressures/temperatures required to produce crystalline minerals. Could you read-up a bit on what the human body is made of, then geochemistry of gem formation, and [edit] to make it clear what you're aiming for.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Ah okay, I'm very sorry for the lack of clarity.

Comment: Depends on what you call a gemstone, on whether they die near the laboratory of a mad chemist, and on what is meant by a short time. However, beware that most gemstones are right out: large diamonds are really hard to make, ruby and sapphire are aluminium oxide (and animals have almost no aluminium in them), emerald is a beryllium aluminium silicate (and animals have almost no beyllium, aluminium or silicon  in them) etc.

Comment: The [tag:magic] tag might be better for this than [tag:science-based] also, just a suggestion.

Comment: Yeah the Resident evil series worries a lot more on the rule of cool than on the plausibility of their concepts. I mean, Lady dimitrescu can form a Dragon body from nothing other than her own mass, just like Derek Simmons could turn into a mutant T-rex-esque abomination, meaning that either they are generating mater from nothing or that they're very dense and that the Dimitrescu castle is built to withstand an extremely heavy behemoth stomping around it with very tiny feet.

Comment: we destroy planets after  breakfast, but this one is impossibru.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. While he will get more answers that way, if he is looking for a science based answer to a question that has none, then it is still a valid question.  There are many science based questions where the answer is "it is impossible".  That alone neither invalidates the question nor the answer as being valid and on topic for discussion.

Comment: This isn't a hard science question, there's lots of vaguely scientific ways to make crystals.

Comment: *What chemical turns keratin into stone?* +1

Comment: If you are looking for an excuse to loot dead vampires, you can just make society consider their teeth to be valuable gemstones: analogously, earth's society considers rhino horns to be 'gemstones' in that they are a stonelike material that can be looted and sold on the black market for a high price

Comment: What's "a relatively short time"?  Do you want "before your very eyes" or just "we're talking days, not geological time"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The vampires, much like clams, have layers of crystal on their blood vessels.**

People often have a lot of sodium in their blood and other crystalline minerals. As such, vampires have crystals lining everywhere where blood has gone within where all the surplus crystal stuff is stored.

This is normal science, as plaques are a common issue for people on earth. It would be unusual to form them as crystals, but not outside normal science.

**When vampires die, they dissolve.**

Their world is formed with hostile enemies, and it proved evolutionary useful for vampires to dissolve in a way that harms whatever attacked it when they die. When they die their biological matter burns away, leaving behind their crystalline blood vessels and fusing the crystals.

This is called Autothysis in nature, and is something ants do to protect their colony, an organ erupting to emit some toxic chemical. This would be a more complete form of such.

**Special vampires have unusual enzyme variants, and can produce more exotic crystals.**

Unusual combinations of enzymes and systems meant to clear blood vessel walls can produce more unusual crystal variants.

Comment: Well Done.  I was having trouble dealing with the science-based tag on this one.   Your solution not only keeps the tags happy, it allows for a beautiful end product, a crystalline vascular system.    Perhaps instead of dissolving/flaking away, the dead vampire combusts and the heat of that final conflagration fuses all of the crystals together into a rigid structure.  +1

Comment: Thank you, exactly what I needed. And I'm very sorry if this post caused any confusion or annoyance to anyone.

Comment: @BelugusBongodier, I wasn't suggesting annoyance... just a lack of good answers which met your requirements of spontaneous crystallization under a science-based tag.  Glad that Nepene Nep was as limited as I.

Comment: @BelugusBongodier I see you are new here, welcome.  It is normally considered good etiquette here to wait at least 24-hours to accept an answer since  it is very common for other better answers to come up from users that have not had the chance to see the question yet.

Comment: This answer is not commensurate with the [tag:science-based] tag, and constitutes a watered down pseudo-scientific explanation at best. We ask that you comment on questions which need clarification or detail, rather than provide "answers".

Comment: The answer requires crystal depositing, the existence of enzymes, plaques, and autothysis. None of those are outside normal science. It would be a weird evolutionary combo, but requires no science outside what is mundanely known.

Answer (score 4):

### Not diamonds... but rubies, sapphires, and emeralds perhaps...

We all know that vampires like to bury themselves in soil to sleep.  What is less well known is that they do this too offset the blood cravings they get after an unsuccessful hunt. Soil has high concentrations of iron oxides; so, when they sleep underground, their skin has adapted to absorb minerals the way that plant roots do so that they can uptake enough iron without having to drink blood specifically.  This way they can supplement their diet as needed with less iron rich food sources like meat and vegetables, and not get sick.  It's like a human taking a multivitamin so they can live off of butter... it's not ideal but it still works...

However, soil is also very full of aluminum oxides.  Unlike iron, animal physiology does not contain a lot of aluminum; so, as the body leeches iron out of the soil, it also gets a lot of aluminum as a waste product that the kidneys then need to filter out.  Then just like humans get kidney stones from eating too much calcium, Vampires are prone to form kidney stones made from aluminum oxides from sleeping in the soil too often... and what are stones made from aluminum oxides you may ask?  Well depending on what impurities you get, this results in rubies, sapphires, and emeralds!

Rubies, sapphires, and emeralds don't require extreme pressure to form the way that diamonds do.  In fact, there are plenty of YouTube videos out there of people you making them in their microwaves in open crucibles.

If you want the vampire to "turn into" the gemstones before your eyes, then you need to handwave in some spontaneous dissolving feature like Nepene Nep suggests, but this is pretty unscientific since there are no examples of this in nature.  A simpler solution if your vampire hunters want to loot the corpses for precious gemstones would be to stop to cut out their kidneys.  It only takes a few moments to do and pretty much all vampires have a few gemstones in there.  The older the vampire the more gemstones you will find.

Comment: Plenty, eh, scientific community on youtube only recently successsfully conquered that peak and there is plenty of videos already, wow, magic of digital redistribution of knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question stated "almost no magic is involved", I'm going to ignore the science-based tag and offer a semi-magical solution.  Even if it doesn't qualify as an answer, it may be helpful to the original poster, in building the legends and lore surrounding this post-mortem crystalline transformation.

A vampire is living carbon's best attempt at immortality.  Immune from aging, therefore theoretically immortal and highly motivated to stay in one piece, being a vampire is carbon's best choice for a long stable existence.  When due to the death of the vampire, the carbon has to find a second best choice, it of course chooses diamonds.

So it isn't the vampire which is magical... it is the carbon that the vampire is made of which has just enough magic to shift from the ultimate stability of being a vampire into the penultima form, diamonds.

Comment: This one is actually is a good handwavium, very much inline with nano machines son - it nanomachines make spores, 0 magic at all, just clark life forms.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the premise similar to the traditional vampire. Most vampires survive for at least a few centuries before meeting their death. Most vampires suck human blood and render these body soulless, sucking literally their victim's soul into them them giving them a more youthful body.

If we posit that within your world there are real entities like souls, it also assigns them a physical state since they can interact with matter, which is the body and take residence in it.

As vampires consume more and more souls, they obtain youth and strength within the same body which gives them that power but they also bear the burden of carrying these many souls, which are physical entities, hence have their own ethereal mass. Due to this, there is an imbalance between the external environment and the vampires body, as there is a lot of mass in the vampire's body in a small volume.

Upon death, as the vampire's body turns into ash within seconds, the environmental pressure rushes in to occupy the void created by souls that instantly left the vampire's body. All that instantaneous pressure on the vampiric ash causes the ash to turn into gem stones. Now depending on what these vampires consumed over their life would give you the type of stone, most old vampires which live beyond 1000 years always accumulate enough mass within them to turn into diamonds if they die.